# Java: How can I find the amount of tiles which fits in?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, size, tiles

Im actually done with my code but somehow it doesn't work like it should. My problem is that I don't know what exactly I need to change so it works like it actually should, Am I rounding false , or...? I'am looking forward for some solutions, thx!

Here is the task:

Write a small application that helps a tiler to estimate how many tiles he needs to tile a floor. For this purpose, the dimensions of the tiles (width and length in mm) should be transferred to the application, as well as the floor area to be tiled in the form of width and length in cm. In addition, the user should be asked about the joint distance (distance between two tiles) in mm.

The application uses this data to calculate how many tiles are needed and print the number on the screen. The fact that tiles can be partially reused should not be taken into account.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("tile width (mm):");
        double tilewidth = (scanner.nextDouble() / 100.0);
        System.out.print("tile length (mm): ");
        double tilelength = (scanner.nextDouble() / 100.0);
        System.out.print("floor width (cm): ");
        double floorwidth = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("floor length (cm): ");
        double floorlength = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("joint spacing (mm): ");
        double jointspacing = (scanner.nextDouble() / 10.0);


        double tilelength1 = 0;
        double tilewidth1 = 0;
        double f2 = tilelength;
        double f2_2 = tilewidth;
        double f3 = 0;


        for (; f2 < floorlength; f2++) {
            tilelength1 = f2;
        }
        tilelength1 = tilelength1 / tilelength;

        double joints = (Math.round(jointspacing * tilelength1));

        double lengtheoftiles = tilelength1 - joints;


        for (; f2_2 < floorwidth; f2_2++) {
            tilewidth1 = f2_2;
        }
        tilewidth1 = tilewidth1 / tilewidth;

        double joints2 = (Math.round(jointspacing * tilewidth1));

        double widthoftiles = tilewidth1 - joints2;


        double needtiles = widthoftiles + lengtheoftiles;

        System.out.println("tiles required:" + Math.round(needtiles);


    }


}
```

[image]

It should work like in the task and with other numbers to.

Comment: Looks complicated for first look, set breakpoint and verify where you have a bug step by step (or maybe some breakpoints, because loops have hundreds of iterations).

Comment: I can see a few problems with this; but one problem is that you've mixed up different units.  You've got `tileWidth` and `tileLength` in decimetres, but `floorWidth`, `floorLength` and `jointSpacing` are in centimetres.

Answer (score 0):

On your solution you are dividing by 100 but you want to divide by 10 to go from mm to cm

On this solution i just calculate the area of the floor - half the jointSpacing  on each side, then calculate the area of the tiles the same way then divide floorArea / tileAreaWithSpacing and round up to get the estimate.

Note: here im counting half tiles as 1 full tile and the jointSpacing is also present near the wall and tile

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double tileWidth = 45 / 10.0;    // tile width (mm)
    double tileLength = 45 / 10.0;   // tile length (mm)
    double floorWidth = 25.5;        // floor width (cm)
    double floorLength = 25.5;       // floor length (cm)
    double jointSpacing = 10 / 10.0; // joint spacing (mm);
    double floorArea = (floorLength - (jointSpacing / 2)) * (floorWidth - (jointSpacing / 2));
    double tileAreaWithSpacing = (tileWidth + (jointSpacing / 2)) * (tileLength + (jointSpacing / 2));
    double numberOfTiles = Math.ceil(floorArea / tileAreaWithSpacing);
    System.out.println(numberOfTiles);
}
```

Output:

```
25.0
```

visual representation of the code:

```
Black is the floor area
Ligth yellow is half of the jointSpacing that goes around the floor area
Green is the other half of the jointSpacing that goes around the tile area
Gray is the tile area
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried your code with the Scanner input and numbers of the example: 420,350,500,500 and 3, but somehow it don't gives me the output of 180. Could you please check that? thx!

Comment: i mean your own code is wrong of course it wont give the same results that gave to you

Comment: and even without the joint space the max num of  tiles is 171 with your inputs so you should never even reach 180 tiles